# Edit a WebView's HTML at runtime

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

Is there a way to show the user a web page and let him edit it? It's enough if the user can put the cursor somewhere, then type a letter, and my code will be informed that the user has typed these characters in this location. My code will then do the rest.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke a javascript code to the loaded web page using the [InvokeScriptAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx) method. Then the javascript code may add a [Content Editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) element to the web page to do all the page related work and also handle events.

In order to interact with the injected javascript in the app (to receive events for example), you need to add a runtime object to the document. See [AddWebAllowedObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.addweballowedobject.aspx%20WebView.AddWebAllowedObject).